# Update broke bind9

Tags: upgrade, updates, bind

I updated today, and now bind9 won't start.

```
[FAIL] Starting domain name service...: bind9 failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript bind9, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing bind9 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bind9
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried dpkg-reconfigure, with the following result:

```
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: bind9 is broken or not fully installed
```

Tried removing, reinstalling, also tried dpkg --configure -a and apt-get install -f

How can I fix this, or where do I start looking for a solution?

Comment: Can you look in /var/log/apt/history.log for today's entries and see what might have affected it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was a misconfigured zone file. But it wasn't one I would have expected, it ended in `.zone.save` extension. I deleted that file, and that seems to have solved that problem.